# How could I send transactions continuously by Web3j generated wrapper

Tags: web3j, java, quorum

I wrote a smart contract and deployed on my private Quorum. I use Web3j to generate java wrapper to call ABIs. For example,

```
// here is a smart contract function
function getMoney() external payable 
{
    Event_GotMoney(msg.value, now);
}
```

In my java, if I call like this

```
contract.getMoney(new BigInteger(100)).send();
// or
// contract.getMoney(new BigInteger(100));
```

I can always get Event_GotMoney event. 
However, if I want to call it continuously, like this, (asynchronized)

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    contract.getMoney(new BigInteger(100));
```

I can't get 100 Event_GotMoney events. The interval of the timestamp in the event is 3 or 10 seconds(depends on the frequency of generating blocks). I guess the nonce isn't updated util a block generated. If my guess is correct, how can I call smart contract functions continuously? If not, is it a limitation or something?

Another small question, I use event observable functions provided by Web3j wrapper. It works well to get events, but it updates every 15 seconds. How could I modify the interval?

Any feedback would be appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, please refer, [#296](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/296)

Use FastRawTransactionManager to speed up your transactions. Use RawTransactionManager to shorten the polling interval. If you need both, use the following code,

```
pollingInterval = 3000; // 3 seconds
FastRawTransactionManager fastRawTxMgr = new FastRawTransactionManager(web3, credentials, new PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor(web3j, pollingInterval, 40));
Contract contract = MyPersonalContract.load(contractAddr, web3, fastRawTxMgr, gasPrice, gasLimit);
```

Comment: the polling interval would be every 3 seconds according to the code, that is, every 3 seconds you will see the transaction to return txHash ?, and the number 40 for what it works?

Comment: No, it means polling the txHash every 3 seconds and retry 40 times. If it over 40 times, it will return error.