# Error processing transaction request: already known

Tags: erc-20, infura, web3j

I'm developing an application with which you can make ERC20 token transfers. When you make transfers from one account to another with a reasonable time between transfers it works correctly.

But when you make many transfers in a very short period of time from one account to another, like making 100 transfers one after another.

To make the transfers I am using the web3j library with version 4.5.15 and connects to the blockchain through Infura.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

I leave you the code where the transfers are executed:

```
StaticGasProvider staticGasProvider = new StaticGasProvider(gasPrice, gasLimit);
TransactionManager transactionManager = new FastRawTransactionManager(web3j, "my_credentials", new NoOpProcessor(web3j));
ERC20 tokenContract = ERC20.load("token_address", web3j, transactionManager, staticGasProvider);
TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = tokenContract.transfer("to_address", "amount").send();
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: The problem might the nonce isn't updated quickly enough. Take a look at this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34502/how-could-i-send-transactions-continuously-by-web3j-generated-wrapper.

Comment: It is very difficult for us to help you if we can't see the code where you create, sign and broadcast the transactions.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I just added the code to make it easier to understand the problem

Answer (score 4):

As commented, showing your code will definitely help.

In the meantime, I also faced this issue from a backend in Node.js when I was launching several transactions almost simultaneously (in a public testnet).

Adding 'pending' when creating the nonce solved the issue:

```
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(params.fromAddress, 'pending');
```

Please let us know if that is your case.